# How can I eliminate typos from being logged in a keylogger?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ideally, I'd like the program to erase/un-log any and all erroneous character(s) when the Backspace key is pressed and replace them with the correct characters.

After searching for solutions to no avail, I'm wondering if it's even possible? If it is, my guess is that the code needed to do this might involve the modules: 're', 'readchar', 'msvcrt', 'getch' or some combination of those, in addition to using 'string.replace', 'x.remove', 'r/R', 'raw_input' 'x.translate', or the like. But I don't have the knowledge or skills yet to figure out how to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

**This code may be what you are looking for:**

```
import re

text = "Helll[Back Space]o how are yoo[Back Space]u"

result = list(text)
for (start, end) in [(m.start(), m.end()) for m in re.finditer('\[Back Space\]', text)]:
    text = text.replace(''.join(result[start-1:end]), '')

print text
```

**Output:**

```
Hello how are you
```